# Creating a list from an output

Tags: python-3.x, list

How do i create list containing the values of the output of a fibonnaci series created below?

```
a,b=1,2  
print(a)  
while b<4000000:  
    print(b)  
    a,b=b,a+b
```

Comment: following what you did it's like @Jtcruthers did, but Fibonacci sequence is 0 1 1 2 3 ... don't you want all the sequence till 3524578?

Answer (score 0):

To keep changes minimal, just initialize a list before the loop, and append to it every time you calculate a number.

```
numbers = []
a, b = 1, 2    
while b < 4000000:  
    numbers.append(a)  
    a, b = b, a + b 
numbers.append(a) #Get that last number after you calculated it last time
```